# Arranging drinks with laid off coworkers in close-knit team

Tags: socializing, layoff

I work in a close-knit team of about 20 that just suffered layoffs. Some of the surviving employees and laid off employees are friends, and several survivors have suggested arranging drinks with the entire former team. Keep in mind that we were all at the same level of the hierarchy, roughly speaking.

I am aware of the potential for this arrangement to be awkward, both because some of us still have jobs and others don't and because the company might not be happy about us getting together. Is it at all advisable for us to meet for drinks and what potential pitfalls should we be aware of to avoid creating problems at work?

Comment: There is a difference between friend and acquaintance and you won't know who your true friends are until you have been locked in a room with them and left to die.

Comment: @emory: Heh, stay positive now

Comment: @emory that escalated quickly

Comment: Not a duplicate, but have a look [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34915/the-company-is-probably-dying-what-should-i-expect-and-how-can-i-prepare/34934#34934). I had no problems meeting with the whole team when about half was laid off.

Comment: @emory How many true friends do you have?  How often do you get locked in a room and left to die?

Comment: @Myles thankfully I don't know because it has never happened to me.  A holocaust survivor could tell you who his true friends are, not me.

Comment: @emory - actually, that's pretty much how they laid us off at one job. About two dozen of us found ourselves in a conference room, then a lady from HR came in and told us all we had been laid off. We were in that room for almost two hours with at least SOME idea of what was about to happen. It wasn't pretty.

Comment: I can't comment due to rep issues. I feel like the primary source of you feeling at all awkward about this confrontation is *this* post itself. You've clearly overthought this to a nearly outlandish extent. People have been getting together for drinks after work for... what, hundreds of years? Just go drinking and have fun, geez!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The company has no business being interested in what you do in your spare time. As long as you keep this outside of work hours, there isn't really much they can do to stop you. However in the interests of not appearing to be in open rebellion against the company you should probably keep this relatively discreet, by which I mean don't put up posters advertising the meetup, and use company email with discretion. Don't send invitations to mailing lists where senior managers or HR might be copied. (However also don't assume that immediate managers are against this meetup - some of them might be interested in joining you).

I would recommend waiting a week or so before meeting. Those let go are going to be understandably angry in the first week or so, no matter how well the layoffs were handled, and during that time any conversation is going to be mostly about what utter, unforgivable, unrelenting bastards the company are. Sometimes that isn't healthy, for either the survivors or non-survivors.

It will also be necessary to be the tiniest bit discreet about company information. Ordinary things you would have shared before shouldn't be a problem, but if the company cancelled a major project, or gave employees financial information right after the layoffs, don't forget they are no longer part of the company.

Comment: (+1) for this: `The company has no business being interested in what you do in your spare time` :)

Comment: Last time I was with a company that made redundancies, they did them first thing in the morning and gave the rank-and-file the rest of the day off so that leaving and remaining staff *could* get together if they wanted to (some did, some went home, and the senior management were working on the redundancy admin). The conversation was not *mostly* about what unrelenting bastards the company was, but employers who are unrelenting bastards may find things go differently ;-p

Comment: If the company *published* financial information right after the layoffs, that's public information so you can discuss it with whomever you want. It may or may not be something that the laid-off staff want to hear about but that's a social issue, not a workplace one.

Comment: _"It will also be necessary to be the tiniest bit discreet about company information"_ Yeah, where "the tiniest bit discreet" actually means "don't mention anything at all". You no longer have the legal right to do so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's good to be aware what the actual legal situation is, but it seems like quite an exaggeration to suggest that all workplaces would have "don't mention anything at all" something that "you no longer have the legal right to do so". I've never had anyone suggest that I had no legal right to mention anything at all about a workplace ... in fact, in almost everyplace I've worked, the assumption has been that only certain specific subjects or details are not expected to be discussed outside the workplace.

Comment: @Dronz: I can't think of much in the way of "company news" that wouldn't be confidential. Could you perhaps give some examples?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just think your comment reads as exaggerated, probably because it's not completely clear what part of the answer you're commenting on - did you mean "you have no legal right to [...] mention anything at all" about information that's meant to be kept confidential? Where I've worked (places where employees are generally treated as adults with good judgement & discretion), there are specific NDA's but people freely talk about most aspects of their workplace or even products that aren't covered. Hours, benefits, workload, tools, non-NDA project stuff...

Comment: @Dronz: Then this is a cultural difference.

Comment: I still do not understand why anyone should be 'understandably angry' for being laid off. This is how the arrangement is, you can leave and they can leave you, it's just business relationship, not the romantic one. Life is change, no reason to be angry, provided that the layoff itself is executed in a professional manner and there is no special context.

Comment: @okolnost: I imagine one reason might be the fact that if you don't give them an adequate notice before leaving, it can come back to bite you later down the road, whereas companies don't usually seem to give advance notice of layoffs and the lack of a comparable repercussion for them this seems unfair, understandably causing people to get angry.

Comment: @Mehrdad Good point. If you have different notice period than your employer then I understand it may be a bit unfair. Is that a common practice in US? In Europe this is not possible, hence my question.

Comment: @okolnost: Yeah, it is. Just scroll up and read [this comment](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69673/69675?noredirect=1#comment192457_69673).

Comment: @Merhdad, it is a common practice for companies laying people off to pay salary through a notice period but tell them not to come to work.  Get paid for doing nothing.

Comment: @emory: I'm not sure how "common" that practice is, because I'm pretty sure I've heard it not being followed, but regardless, I *did* say "adequate notice before leaving", not "adequate notice before pay stops". That said, your comment would be better directed at the one I referred to, rather than mine.

Answer (score 9):

To build upon the excellent answer by DJClayworth, I suggest you not only meet with the former colleagues, but keep an active relationship with them. It has saved my team a lot of time and effort when former colleagues stopped by to chat and were happy to help us tie up the odd loose end on some problem they were working on before they were let go.

But it's not only about getting them to work for free. Keeping a network of alumni helps to improve the image of the company and often supplies a number of skilled people to hire.

This answer was inspired by [this article](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Up-or-Out-Solving-the-IT-Turnover-Crisis) by Alex Papadimoulis. While I don't necessarily agree with everything he writes, there are certainly some very good points.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should meet, your company can't dictate who you spend your free time with and your friends could do with some camaraderie right about now.

The only pitfall I would warn you of is that *if* the employed demographic is the one that made the invite, they are *implicitly* suggesting that they will foot the bill: make sure you confirm this with the rest of the job-holders beforehand.

Comment: *"your company can't dictate who you spend your free time with"*... can't? Really? Can't they fire you for this if they really do feel like it? What does "at-will employment mean" otherwise? If anything, it means they can dictate pretty much whatever they want as long you're their employee...